# Change menus and menu items programmatically in Eclipse E4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am having trouble removing existing menus from the model, in a running app.
For example:

```
MMenu menu = modelService.findElements(app, "idMenuFoo", MMenu.class, 
    Collections.<String>emptyList(), EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU).get(0);
menu.setLabel("X");
menu.setVisible(false);
menu.setToBeRendered(false);
```

After this code gets executed:

- The label has been changed to 'X'
- But the menu entry is still visible/rendered

If I start the app without clearPersistedState, then restart it, the menu has disappeared. This leads me to be believe the the visibility and rendering attributes were set in the first place, but not applied to the model (unlike the label attribute).

How can I programmatically trigger a main menu bar "refresh" after such changes?

Comment: Why aren't you using the more normal 'visible when' expression on the menu definition?

Comment: If this is a top level menu you may be hitting bug [365724](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365724)

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, that was it. I'm refreshing the menu manually now, although that introduces an explicit dependency on SWT at the RCP model level. Not great, in that case, a visibleWhen expression (which I was carefully avoiding till then) might be better suited

Answer (score 1):

As a Greg in the comment above posted, there is an open bug filed to address this issue. An easy to implement a workaround involves manually refreshing the underlying SWT menu. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365724#c9 for details. In a gist:

```
// retrieve the main menu, containing the top-level menu element that needs to be refreshed
MMenu mainMenu = ...

// org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.MenuManagerRenderer
MenuManagerRender renderer = (MenuManagerRenderer)mainMenu.getRenderer();
renderer.getManager(mainMenu).update(true);
```